# App dock icon in wxPython

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

In wxPython on Mac OS X is it possible to display a custom icon when an application is launched. Right now when I launch the app I wrote, a blank white icon is displayed in the dock. How would I go about changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this in my setup file to add an icon:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['MyApp.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 
    'iconfile': 'MyAppIcon.icns' }

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I think you have to use an icns file. I used [img2icns](http://www.img2icnsapp.com/) to create one.